# What is the Best Practice in EaselJS for Ticker

Tags: html, canvas, easeljs

Currently the problem I'm running into is, when I'm running locally (in a ubuntuVM), using WebStorm as a webserver, I run my game and it plays fine and its responsive, but when I uploaded it to my webhosting and play it from there it is laggy and the click events aren't responsive.

I think it is because I'm using Ticker incorrectly (How do you call update for stages?):

```
canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", canvas);
```

and all containers, sprites, etc are children of this stage

http://thegamingproject.org/webgames/ludumdare28/ <- lagginess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To address the lag, I would suggest you first look into adjusting your FPS on the `Ticker`. Check out the documentation [here](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Ticker.html#method_setFPS).  You may also want to experiment with the [enableMouseOver frequency](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_enableMouseOver). Be careful with animations, and take advantage of [caching](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_cache) before doing alpha fades etc. I have found the [easeljs](/questions/tagged/easeljs) library will lag a bit with a lot of detailed vector content (such as when exported from the Flash IDE). Use `Bitmaps` when you can to limit the drawing instructions.

As for the Ticker listener, as I see it you have the following 2 options:

### 1. Add the stage as a listener to the Ticker

This is the easiest to manage, though it gives you the least amount of control over rendering. According to [this createjs tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/), this is only recommended for quick tests.

**Example**

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

**Advantages**

- The `stage.update()` is called automatically for each tick
- Low maintenance or logic required

**Disadvantages**

- Lowest amount of control on when changes are reflected on stage
- May not be the best solution for a "real-time" game

### 2. Calling stage.update() in custom function(s)

This solution allows manual control for updating the stage. This could be useful if you need to "pause" content from updating (like a game for instance).

**Example**

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

function tick(){
     var isDirty = false;
     //some custom logic

     if(isDirty) {
          stage.update();

     }
}
```

**Advantages**

- Complete control over when drawing changes are reflected on the stage.
- May be able to improve performance by not updating every tick

**Disadvantages**

- Potential to introduce performance issues by adding too much custom logic to each tick
- Requires more overhead to manage

Comment: Regarding 1) it's not possible to do a time-based animation right? I would need the time info from the event. Is that the case?

Comment: @MatthiasMax You can indeed do time based animations. In fact they recommend it because it ensures the animations will run the same amount of time, regardless of frame rate. [source](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Animation%20and%20Ticker/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wonder where to put the logic for the delta when you don't have a tick function (as it would be the case in 1) ).

Comment: There's nothing saying you can't add multiple tick listeners to the ticker, but I think you should probably get to know the [TweenJS](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) library that is part of CreateJS. It should reduce some of that overhead for writing custom animations.